VS Code tab completion inside snippet prevented by placeholder
I want to achieve the following:

the editor does not select any suggestions (but it shows so I can select with arrow keys), this is achieved by "editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never";
when I type (exact) prefix for snippets I can tab complete it without choose it with arrow keys, this is achieved by "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets";
I want that two behaviors able to nest so I make sure "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false.

most of the time those works fine but when i tried to tab complete snippets within tab completed snippet, I can't tab complete it unless the placeholder is $0. When I reach a placeholder, whatever I type is highlighted and when I type prefix and tab I go to next placeholder instead of tab complete that.... In this case I need to manually type ESC to escape the highlights..


Any fix to this?

how deep do you want to be able to nest snippet expansion, when in a snippet VSC is in Snippet-mode, a special UI state. I don't think it allows nesting snippets. What if you use Ctrl+Space when you are in snippet mode.

@rioV8 I want to go as deep as possible (just like I do in Vim, where I use vim-snippets and UltiSnippets). If I hit Cotrol+Space I change my input method on MacOS (command space will go to spotlight search).
Basically I want that when I am in Snippet mode, tab complete have more priority over moving to next placeholder. Is this possible?

look for the key binding for the command Trigger Suggest

Thanks @rioV8! I have found a workaround to this in case anyone need :)
I override the key in the following way
{
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && hasSnippetCompletions && !editorTabMovesFocus"
}

i.e., remove !inSnippetMode
